# Filtering specific lines

Tags: logstash

I am currently trying to filter specific lines from my log file. My lines in the log file are of the following pattern.

```
[8/05/13 14:24:55.468] RuntimeErrorI E LaError
[8/05/13 14:24:55.468] AbcdEfg W SomeWarning
```

where the first is the date, time, application name and the Log level( WARNING, ERROR, TRACE etc) followed by the error message or warning message or any other messages.

So what I am trying to get is the log level errors only and not other log levels.
I have the following which I am playing around with but I am not getting console output at all. I think I am making a mistake somewhere in my grep for checking if its E(Error)

```
input {

  file {
  type => "database"
  path => "/home/nakampe/Desktop/file.log"
  }

}

filter {

 grok {

    pattern =>  "[%{MONTHDAY:date} / %{MONTH:month} / %{YEAR:year}  %{TIME:time}] %WORD:application} %{WORD:levelType}  %{WORD:message}"

  }


#Here I want to only consider log levels of E (ERROR) and not others
  grep{

  match => ["levelType", "E"]

  }

}

output {

   elasticsearch { 

   embedded => true 
   }

stdout { 
  message => "%{@message}"
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 grok { 

pattern =>  "%{MONTHDAY:date}/%{MONTHNUM:month}/%{YEAR:year} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:sast}]      

    %{INT:threadId} %{WORD:applicationName}%{SPACE:space}%{WORD:logLevel} %     {WORD:errorMessage}"

}
```

My mistake was with the pattern, after debugging using http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ all was ok. A very useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to chain both filters otherwise they will be applied independently to the original line. You can do this by adding a tag in the grok filter and react to this in the grep filter:

```
grok {
  pattern => ...
  add_tag => [ "groked_input" ]
}
```

and

```
grep {
  match => ...
  tags => [ "groked_input"]
}
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Hi Jayeff, thanks for the reply, really appreciate the input. I am sorry I didn't post my solution soon to say I managed to do it. My mistake was with the grok pattern as it had errors which I couldn't see when I was busy parsing the events, so I debugged it using the grok online editor and I figure out why my tests were not passing because of my pattern errors. I fixed the pattern and everything fell into place. I shall fidget with what you suggested as well to enhance my learning curve. And thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

under the grok section

```
if [levelType] != "ERROR" {
        drop { }
}
```